# Twilio Twiml(response) gives xml exception

Tags: c#, .net, twilio

After updating my Twilio nuget package to 5.8.0, I'm getting an error when trying to return TwiML.

```
        var response = new MessagingResponse();
        response.Message("Hello world");
        return TwiML(response);
```

This code breaks in Visual Studio and throws an XML exception at line 1 position 1. The code before the update:

```
        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        response.Sms("Hello world");
        return TwiML(response);
```

Worked exactly as expected, but now throws the same error. What am I missing here?

EDIT

So I created a whole new MVC project that uses Twilio v5.8.0. This is the all that I added:

```
public class HomeController : TwilioController
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Text()
    {
        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        response.Sms("Hello world");
        return TwiML(response);
    }
}
```

This gives me the same error as before.

When I switched back to v5.7.2 it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is a known issue between `Twilio.AspNet.Mvc` and version 5.8.0 of the Twilio package. We are working on it, but the current advice is to go back to version 5.7.2.

**Update**

The issue is solved in `Twilio.AspNet.Mvc`. Please update to [`Twilio` 5.8.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio/5.8.1) and [`Twilio.AspNet.Mvc` 5.8.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio.AspNet.Mvc/5.8.1).

Comment: Wish I had known this, best part of a day wasted! Emailed support on Friday and still haven't heard back. Updated as couldn't nest a say in a gather 5.7.2. Would appreciate an update on here or to my ticket when its resolved.

Comment: Ah! What code were you using to nest a `<Say>` in `<Gather>`? I'm sure that could be done in 5.7.2. (I'll find the ticket internally and update here as soon as I know when this is fixed though.)

Comment: have downgraded and managed to get it working, I think it would nest, but the `say` would complete before it started to listen to the DTMF presses. Thankfully 4.7.2 is now working!
Had to switch back the uri/url syntax/type for gather. Are there many changes in syntax for 5.8? If so I would rather hold off than trawl through code to bring it inline once its released. Cheers

Comment: There is a pull request open to fix this in Twilio.AspNet.Mvc now: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-aspnet/pull/4

Comment: Good news, `Twilio.AspNet.Mvc` has been fixed, please upgrade to version 5.8.1 of both libraries.